# start a filter that asks for runQueryOnBackgroundThread

Tags: android, autocomplete, filtering, android-cursoradapter

If I implement filtering for an `autocomplete` and I override the `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` method, a background thread will be launched  which will get me a cursor.

That cursor will be set to my `CursorAdapter`, but what else should I do in order to have the entries of the `autocomplete` filtered?

Should I set up a filter?

This is my code:

```
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
    if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
        return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
    }

    String filter="";

    if(constraint==null)
        filter="";
    else 
        filter=constraint.toString();

    Cursor cursor=db.getCursor(filter);

    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The class that implements runQueryOnBackgroundThread must implements filterable. And let's assume this class is called A.
2. setup a listener on a textview so that whenever something changes, you run a.getFilter().filter(s) where "a" is an instance of A and "s" is the text you want to use to as an arguments to runQueryOnBackgroundThread.